# Column `D1` in field list is ambigious

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

wondering if you can help me solve this one.

Typically if you want to run an INSERT with a join you'd use a script like the one i've written here...

```
    INSERT INTO products_BU  (`d1`)
      SELECT `D1`
      FROM new_dimensions_BU
      LEFT JOIN new_dimensions_BU AS ud 
      ON products_BU.size_code = ud.SIZE_CODE
```

Here's the conundrum, In products_BU there is no field that is exactly `D1`, in addition even if there were it would be simple for me to just use an alias for that column, however. if I use the alias ud.D1 I get another issue in that it says Unknown column 'products_BU.size_code' in 'on clause' even though I can see it is exactly size_code.

If I remove the alias I get once again Ambiguous column, so removing the alias doesn't work either.

Can anybody shed some light on why an error such as this would occur?

Comment: *In products_BU there is no field that is exactly D1*, how can this be?, you are using `INSERT INTO products_BU(d1)`, so `d1` **must** exist in that table

Comment: yes but surely they are different because of the capital in `D1`? and even if they were the same and I used an alias, it still fails.

Comment: You have this join predicate - `products_BU.size_code = ud.SIZE_CODE` - yet `products_BU` does not appear in the select list, this is why you get the unknown column error. I suspect you want `new_dimensions_BU.size_code = ud.SIZE_CODE`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your explanation of your issue with the actual problem. You most likely just are confusing your whole problem, and you need to understand how to use table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a query like this:

```
insert into table2
(field1, field2, etc)
select query goes here
```

The select query has to be able to execute successfully on it's own.

Looking at this code:

```
FROM new_dimensions_BU
LEFT JOIN new_dimensions_BU AS ud 
ON products_BU.size_code = ud.SIZE_CODE
```

You are attempting to reference the products table without joining to it.